# Arranging Objects in an Array/Vector into a Grid

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, vector, grid

I want to arrange certain objects from a vector/array into a gird

Currently, I know how to do this during the creation of the objects.

Here's the grid function I've created:

```
function ArrangeInGrid(uiRow:uint, uiCol:uint, iOffsetX:int, iOffsetY:int):void
{
     for(var i:uint = 0; i < uiRow; ++i)
     {
          for(var j:uint = 0; j < uiCol; ++j)
          {
               var card:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
               card.x += iOffsetX + i * card.width;
               card.y += iOffsetY + j * card.height;
               stage.addChild(card);
          }
     }
}
```

Now I want to be able to apply the same logic of arranging objects in an array/vector in to a grid, how do I do it?

Or suggest a more efficient way to do so (if you have).

Notes:

- I want it to be flexible in how many rows and columns the grid can have.
- The vector I'm using already has the cards in it.
- I can't just push the cards into the vector cuz of the way I manually created my cards.

Let me know if you need any more info.

---

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[hx3ds](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=569) (formerly [as3ds](http://lab.polygonal.de/?page_id=179)) by Michael Baczynski comes with a couple of MultiDimensional structures which are well suited and optimised for grid-type data (such as a tile map).  [Full source code is also avaliable](http://code.google.com/p/polygonal/) for [these structures](http://code.google.com/p/polygonal/source/browse/trunk/src/lib/de/polygonal/ds/Array3.hx) should you be interested in what's going on under the hood and there's a [PDF](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=2513) which provides a great introduction to the library.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a one dimensional array containing uiRow x uiCol elements.

```
function ArrangeInGrid(cards:Vector.<MovieClip>, uiRow:uint, uiCol:uint, iOffsetX:int, iOffsetY:int):void
{
     var arrayIndex:uint;

     for(var i:uint = 0; i < uiRow; ++i)
     {
          for(var j:uint = 0; j < uiCol; ++j)
          {
               var card:MovieClip = cards[arrayIndex++];
               card.x += iOffsetX + i * card.width;
               card.y += iOffsetY + j * card.height;
               stage.addChild(card);
          }
     }
}
```